# Mysql filtering data based on datetime from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We monthly do rotation backup of mysql entries in different tables. Table names are combiantion of month+year.

e.g

```
012013 - for jan 2013
022014 - for feb 2014.
```

These all tables have same schema.

So how to filter data based on given date range from there different tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Putting similar data into different tables is a bad idea.  You should have a single table, and then you can use partitions to split the data by month.  See the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html).

With your structure, you can create a view:

```
create view v_table as
    select 2013 as year, 1 as month, t.* from t_012013 t union all
    select 2013, 2, t.* from t_022013 t union all
    . . .;
```

This will not be very efficient for querying.  It will accomplish your purpose.  The right solution is to use partitioning and keep all the data in a single table.